# Add ssh key into Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket

I am using bitbucket deploy with Elastic Beanstalk.
I have one private repository. I have to add SSH key into EC2 instance, which will be using when EB run `npm install`.
What is the best way to do this?

**Update**
I packed node_modules and package-lock.json from the build step.
And I don't need to run `npm install` on the deployment step.
Thank you @StefanN for good question.

Comment: So you want to ssh into the eb instance?

Comment: @Marcin No, I want to run `npm install` with private repository (I have custom repository into package.json). On local dev env, I added ssh key for that repository. When I deploy on EB it cannot run `npm install` because access denied for private repository.

Comment: Are you running `npm install` as a part of your deployment pipeline?

Comment: Looks like EB run it. But I ran it on build pipeline, than create application.zip, and looks like EB run `npm install` again

Comment: @StefanN nice suggestion. Right now I want to know, how do not run `npm install` when I deploy application using EB.

Comment: OK so we solved the first problem in your original question, right?

Comment: I solved all question. Right now I deployed app and do not need any ssh keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way - after build application packed `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`. After that you don't need to install any additional modules.

@StefanN thank you for sending me on the right path